# Trouble reinstalling ubuntu without removing other partitions on disk

Tags: system-installation, boot-partition

I installed ubuntu 17.04 on my whole hard-drive, then shrunk the root partition and created another partition(say sda2). Now, I want to downgrade to 16.04 LTS but when I run installation using LIVE usb, there is no option to just reinstall ubuntu without removing the other partition(sda2). Is there is a way so that I can reinstall ubuntu without removing sda2?
Please help.

Comment: Try choosing **Something else** option and install 16.04 in the old root partition (sda1?): https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: The $64,000 question is... why downgrade to 16.04? Are you trying to solve a specific problem with 17.04?

Comment: @pomsky I tried that but then all the other partitions that are autocreated will be unused and that I don't want. I want that only those partitions concerning to my Ubuntu installation be modified.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, after installing gnome version, even the light use of system occupies around 4GBs of RAM and the system response time is analogous to windows 98. Also, keyboard shortcuts ain't working and system freezes often. After having multiple such problems, I want to revert back to my old Ubuntu version.

Comment: Even with the problems you cite, I'd recommend hashing them out. 17.10 is two weeks away, and unless you stick with 16.04 forever, you'll have to fix them some time if you ever plan on upgrading. Do you have the Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 installed now? What processor do you have? How much RAM/swap? Show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Do you have encrypted swap? If you post a screenshot of `gparted` I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you erase the hard drive and then install Ubuntu 16.04? If you have personal files you want to save already on the hard drive, just save them onto DVDs before you erase the hard drive. That's what I do.

Comment: That might not be possible since my sda2 partition is close to 850 GBs and my primary motivation behind asking this question.